# Proxy API call with Express in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch-api

I am using fetch method for API  from my react app.  Now I want to create express app and route this API call from express server.
This part of api is fix : `https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/` rest are user selected value. Then I create URL like this `https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/${section}/${sort}/${window}/${page}?showViral=${viral}`
where I take section, sort, window, page,viral value and pass using `${{section}}` and other in same way depending upon user selection but by default every param is assign if user not select any one filter from UI.

Now I want https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/ in express and send `/${section}/${sort}/${window}/${page}?showViral=${viral}` from below method to express and receive back response.

I have install express in my react app. Rest I am new to it so I am not able to configure.

This `loadImage` method is in react component.

```
 createURL ()
{
 const { lastSection, lastSorting, lastWindow, page, viral } = this.state;
let url = `https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/${section}/${sort}/${window}/${page}?showViral=${viral}`;

    this.loadImages(url);
}
    loadImages(iUrl) {
        let myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Client-ID {{myid}}");
    
        let requestOptions = {
          method: "GET",
          headers: myHeaders,
          redirect: "follow"
        };
        fetch(iUrl, requestOptions)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) =>
            this.setState({ dataList: json.data, loaded: true, showLoader: false })
          )
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to send image `URL` from Express API end-point instead of constructing it by passing parameters.Then, all you need to do is:

For URLSearchParams, you can refer [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString)

```js
createURL ()
{
    const { lastSection, lastSorting, lastWindow, page, viral } = this.state;
    let url = `/getImageURLS`;

    this.loadImages(url, { lastSection, lastSorting, lastWindow, page, viral });
}
    loadImages(iUrl, params) {
        let URL = new URL(iUrl);
        URL.search = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();

        let myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Client-ID {{myid}}");

        let requestOptions = {
          method: "GET",
          headers: myHeaders,
          redirect: "follow"
        };
        fetch(URL, requestOptions)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) =>
            this.setState({ dataList: json.data, loaded: true, showLoader: false })
          )
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
```

Express API end-point:

```js
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let app = express();
app.use('/', router);
app.listen('8080', () => console.log('listening on 8080'));
router.get('/getImageURLS', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query); //shows query paramters sent

    // your logic 

    const obj = [];
    res.send(obj); // image url array to be sent
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help but i am looking for express code only ,.. How to create YOUR_EXPRESS_API_END_POINT in express

Comment: i have to create server.js in public or inside source of react . also In express code you wrote you logic but i want fetched data to send to react .in this line ...then((json) =>
            this.setState({ dataList: json.data, loaded: true, showLoader: false })

Comment: getImageURLS will be replace by https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/

Comment: Does this answers your question ?